# Getting SQL queries generated with Entity Framework Plus?

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-plus

I am enjoying the features of [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net) over Entity Framework 6 since a few hours, and especially its [IncludeFilter](https://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter).

With regular Entity Framework 6, I was able to simply call ToString() on an IQueryable to easily get the SELECT query that will be actually processed on DB Server.

But with EF+, when I apply an IncludeFilter, I only get :

```
 Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryIncludeFilterParentQueryable`1[MyRecord]
```

Because `ToString()` seems to not be overloaded the same way in EF+.

Is there a way to get SQL generated for "IncludeFilter" queries as well as for classical queries ?

I know I could get it on SQL server itself with the adequate profiling tools, but I would like to be able to do it on code side in EF.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to get SQL generated for "IncludeFilter" queries as well as for classical queries ?

No, there is currently no way.

It might come later but at this moment, the library doesn't offer this feature.

(I'm the owner)

**EDIT: Answer comment**

> My main worry was to know if the generated queries are optimized

I would not call them optimized. They are generated by Entity Framework and nothing is really modified on our side.

- IncludeFilter: Create one VERY big query like `Include` does in EF6
- IncludeOptimized: Create multiple small queries like `Include` does in EF Core

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My main worry was to know if the generated queries are optimized (only one call to DB, filter applied in JOIN) and if the generated query was as efficient as for classical EF if I do an IncludeFilter with only a table name without any restrictions. I have checked the behavior in code and it seems fine, but I don't what's done on SQL Server side. Thank you for your great library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the current context's log to track all requests performed under this instance

```
        context.Database.Log = s => Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late but you could use SQL Server Profiler to trace database events (e.g., queries). Using SQL Tuning profile it will trace your queries and you can have a look at them in SQL.

Comment: Of course it's a "general fallback solution" to address this kind of needs, but I was needing a solution that could be enabled in the application itself and that allows to easily correlate queries with their requesting process by logging them at the right place. But it can still be useful in development stage. Thanks anyway.